# e2e test failed to run TypeError: mongoose.Schema is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

> When i run my test e2e, i get this message
>
> ```
> Test suite failed to run
>
>     TypeError: mongoose.Schema is not a constructor
>
>       at Object.<anonymous> (../src/dbschema/test.schema.ts:2:43)
>
> Where test.schema file is:
>
>     import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
>
>     export const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
>       id: {
>         type: Number,
>         required: true,
>       },
>     });
>
> Can somebody help me?
> ```
>
> I bring more details: I would execute a e2e test with using nestjs
>   framework this is the code: 
>       import request from 'supertest';
>       import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
>       import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
>       import { GameModule } from '../src/game/game.module';
>
> ```
> describe('Games', () => {
>   let app: INestApplication;
>
>   beforeAll(async () => {
>     const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
>       imports: [GameModule],
>     })
>       .compile();
>
>     app = await module.createNestApplication();
>     await app.init();
>   });
>
>  The TestSchema is used in an other schema which is GameSchema 
>
> import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
> import { TestSchema } from './test.schema';
>
> export const GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
> price: {
>     type: PriceSchema,
>     required: true,
>   },
> });
> ```

Comment: Smells like a build error - I see that your code is in TypeScript - add a `console.log(mongoose)` and tell us waht it logs.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `new` operator and just do `export const TestSchema = mongoose.Schema({ ... })`?

Comment: Does it work when you run the app normally and only fail in the test environment?